# How to convert DB rows into a training matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like that:

```
index  group1 group2 field_id  value  data
  0      1     1        1        1     12
  1      1     1        1        2     12
  2      1     1        2        1     12
  3      1     1        3        2     12
  4      1     2        1        1     12
  5      1     2        3        1     12
  6      1     2        4        1    ...
  7      1     2        2        2
  8      1     2        1        1
  9      1     3        1        1
  10     2
  11     ...
```

And I want to transform it into a `numpy` matrix:

```
index group2 field_id_1 field_id2 field_3 field_id_4 data
  0      1        1,2        1        2       0       12
```

So I want to gather the `value` of each `field_ids` into column. 
Each row is a `group2` , the `field_ids` are the same across `(group1, group2)` and `data` is per `group2`.

Is there a way of doing this conversion efficiently ? 
I tried with some `groupby` and `forloop` but it is pretty slow.

The end goal is to have those as training and result the first columns with `field_ids` are the input and the `data` column is the output. And each row is a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with a `groupby` to merge values for a same field:

```
In [22]: df
Out[22]: 
   index  group1  group2  field_id  value  data
0      0       1       1         1      1    12
1      1       1       1         1      2    12
2      2       1       1         2      1    12
3      3       1       1         3      2    12
4      4       1       2         1      1    12
5      5       1       2         3      1    12

In [54]: grouped = df.groupby(['group1', 'group2', 'field_id']).agg({'value': lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, x)), 'data': np.min}).reset_index()

In [55]: grouped
Out[55]: 
   group1  group2  field_id  data value
0       1       1         1    12  1, 2
1       1       1         2    12     1
2       1       1         3    12     2
3       1       2         1    12     1
4       1       2         3    12     1
```

We can now use a `pivot_table` to transform the ids into columns:

```
In [56]: grouped.pivot_table(values='value', index=['group2', 'data'], columns='field_id', aggfunc='first').reset_index()
Out[56]: 
field_id  group2  data     1     2  3
0              1    12  1, 2     1  2
1              2    12     1  None  1
```

The numbers refer to the `field_id` values (which you can prepend at your convenience, if that's unclear)

Comment: that seem to work but you are missing the `data` field. and how am I turning that into a numpy matrix ?

Comment: also, i need to pivot, to have each value of `field_id` as a column

Comment: and the `value` column as the value of the cell

Comment: @Wonay so if I understand correctly, a value of 1 in the field_id column whoud become field_id1, and the value column should be the value in this column ?

Comment: yes ! it doesnt have to become `field_id1` it can stay as `1`. I am very closed to a solution right now using `pivot_table`

Comment: @Wonay got it as well, updating my answer right now

Comment: it works pretty well ! What if I had two `data` column ? I tried to add a third name to the `index` parameter but the result dataframe is empty

Comment: @Wonay did you remember to also add this `data2` column in the `grouped` computation ? Can you give me an example ?

Comment: exactly the same thing as before, except that you have one `data` and one `data2` in the original data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154945/discussion-between-3kt-and-wonay).